# basic product repository save not work in cron - magento2

Tags: magento2, cron, sku, crontab, magento2.0.8

I tried the below code in **custom controller** and **cron job** method [just **load** and **save**] after that I felt some issues

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(548);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

**From Controller:**

- It change the product type from **simple** to **virtual**
- No issues in product detail page
- It removes the product from category page.

**From Cron**

- It change the product type from **simple** to **virtual**
- product detail page goes to 404 page not found
- It removes the product from category page.

---

### Update

I checked the same in **Magento 2.1.3**

**From Cron**

- It change the product type from **simple** to **virtual**
- No issues in product detail page
- It removes the product from category page.

***is there any limitation to use product repository in cron? or did I something wrong?***

Comment: Did anybody report a core-issue on github for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mismatch object to  save a update product info. I tried blow code using corn its works for me.

```
 $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product_id);
 $product->setName("Testing");
 $product->save();
```

**Update:**

I saw  `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository::save()` same way to save product, its works for me.

I use

```
 $this->productRepository->save($target, $saveOptions = false);
```

Instread of below line

```
  $this->productRepository->save($target);
```

Comment: could you look at this `module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository::save()`, it seems like pass the product as the argument. by the way I tried you suggestion but it is not work in `2.0.8`